# Calculator that can handle any number of numbers and respects order of operation

Tags: java, calculator

The next thing I will work on is parentheses. Do you think it would be smarter to split the input into 2 lists, one for operators and one for numbers?

Also, is there anything I can/should improve?

```
public class T11 {

    static boolean repeatTry = true;
    private static Scanner sInput;
    static boolean quit2;
    static String repeat;
    static boolean repeat2 = true;

    /**
     * main method. it calls the other methods into action
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true) {

            List<String> inputA = getsInputPreFilter();

            double solution = calculation(inputA);
            System.out.println(solution);

        }
    }

    /**
     * This method creates an array of inputs for the calculation. Input starts with
     * a number, spaces are not required.
     */
    public static List<String> getsInputPreFilter() {
        String a;
        sInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the calculation");
        a = sInput.nextLine();

        // This splits the input into numbers and not numbers
        List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)")));
        int arrayLength = inputList.size();
        if (inputList.get(0).equals("quit")) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (arrayLength == 1) {
            System.out.println(inputList.get(0));
        }

        return inputList;
    }

    /**
     * this calculation calculates any given amount of numbers; it respects the
     * order of operation
     */
    public static double calculation(List<String> preFilteredList) {
        List<String> filteredList;
        int operatorIndex = 1;
        boolean hasCalculated = false;
        // checks if any more operators are left
        while (preFilteredList.contains("*") || (preFilteredList.contains("/")) || (preFilteredList.contains("+"))
                || (preFilteredList.contains("-"))) {


            System.out.println(preFilteredList + "a" + operatorIndex);


            // get the two numbers used in the calculation
            boolean replace = false;
            double numberOne = Double.parseDouble(preFilteredList.get(operatorIndex - 1));
            double numberTwo = Double.parseDouble(preFilteredList.get(operatorIndex + 1));

            // Calculates everything 
            if (preFilteredList.contains("*")) {
                if (preFilteredList.get(operatorIndex).equals("*")) {
                    preFilteredList.set(operatorIndex + 1, (numberOne * numberTwo) + "");
                    replace = true;
                }
            } else if (preFilteredList.contains("/")) {
                if (preFilteredList.get(operatorIndex).equals("/")) {
                    preFilteredList.set(operatorIndex + 1, (numberOne / numberTwo) + "");
                    replace = true;
                }
            } else if (preFilteredList.contains("+")) {
                if (preFilteredList.get(operatorIndex).equals("+")) {
                    preFilteredList.set(operatorIndex + 1, (numberOne + numberTwo) + "");
                    replace = true;
                }
            } else if (preFilteredList.contains("-")) {
                if (preFilteredList.get(operatorIndex).equals("-")) {
                    preFilteredList.set(operatorIndex + 1, (numberOne - numberTwo) + "");
                    replace = true;
                }
            }


            System.out.println(preFilteredList + "b" + operatorIndex);


            // It only removes the lines in the List once it calculated them
            if (replace == true) {
                preFilteredList.remove(operatorIndex - 1);
                preFilteredList.remove(operatorIndex - 1);
                System.out.println("REPLACED");
            } else {
                operatorIndex = operatorIndex + 2;
                System.out.println("ADDED");
            }

            // once it
            if (operatorIndex >= preFilteredList.size()) {
                operatorIndex = 1;
            }


            System.out.println(preFilteredList + "c" + operatorIndex);


        }

        filteredList = preFilteredList;

        double solution = Double.parseDouble(filteredList.get(0));
        return solution;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no graceful way to end the program. the program should accept some input like "quit" and exit gracefully.
2. regarding `"-"` as minus: you should take care to support when user specifies a negative number. this is also true for `"+"` (user may wish to explicitly specify positive number)
3. your calculation doesn't seem to take precedence into account. you know, multiplication and division before adding/substraction. and suport for parenthesis will make this even harder.  You should consider converting the input infix format to postfix.  this is also known as [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) and its biggest advantage is that it does not need parenthesis to specify precedence.
4. The specification of the operators as string values is problematic for two reasons: 1) you do not detect typo and 2) if you want to support more operators (like '%' or '^' (power of)) you need to remember to make changes in several places the code. a solution for 1) is to use enum:

   ```
       public enum Operator {
           PLUS("+"),
           MINUS("-"),
           MULTIPLE("*"),
           DIVIDE("/");

           private String symbol;

           Operator(String symbol) {
               this.symbol = symbol;
           }

           // throws IllegalArgumentException for unrecognized input
           public static Operator fromSymbol(String symbol) {
               return Arrays.stream(Operator.values())
                   .filter(op -> op.symbol.equals(symbol))
                   .findFirst().orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
           }
       }
   ```

then you can replace the String comparison with

```
        if (Operator.fromSymbol(preFilteredList.get(operatorIndex)) == Operator.MINUS) {
```

a solution for 2) is to have a separate class+method for each operator with a common interface. it so happens that Java already have a functional interface for a binary operator:

```
        public enum Operator {
            PLUS("+", ((num1, num2) -> num1 + num2)),
            MINUS("-", ((num1, num2) -> num1 - num2)),
            MULTIPLE("*")...,  // same principal
            DIVIDE("/")...;

            private String symbol;
            private BinaryOperator<Double> mathOperator;

            Operator(String symbol, BinaryOperator<Double> mathOperator) {
                ...
            }

            public double apply (double num1, double num2) {
                return mathOperator.apply(num1, num2);
            }
        }
```

and there you have it: the enum and its implementation in one line. Adding new operatos is quite easy (and safe) with this construct

Comment: it does take it into account, by first calculating * IF any exist, ELSE it goes to /,then to + and -.

The problem tho is, that (6/7)*5 isnt 6/(7*5). At the moment it first calculates the second one (6/35) while the answer should be (30/7)